# My .exe file is not running while my .py file is running fine

Tags: python, kivy, exe, boxlayout, ids

I have wrote a python application with kivy.

I want to create a file with an .exe extension from my python application but when I use the auto-py-to-exe program which allows to create an .exe file from a python file, the file is created correctly, however at launch of my .exe file, the application does not launch and I do not understand why the error returned is this.

I also tried via pyinstaller but the problem remains the same. I think it comes from the code but the code works fine on my VScode so I don't understand that it can't run in .exe.

Here is the errors returned :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
KeyError: 'top_box'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myvide.py", line 462, in <module>
  File "kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
  File "kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
  File "myvide.py", line 198, in build
  File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

"top_box" is the identifier of a BoxLayout that I use to put several information in it, so I can't simply remove it.

Here is the 198th line : `self.topicsSelectionScreen.ids.top_box.add_widget(self.header)`

Here is my github with the code : https://github.com/sdourte/MyVideGraff.git

Thank you.

Comment: The error suggests that your `TopicsSelectionScreen` does not have an `id` of `top_box`. That can happen if your `kv` file is not being loaded. Is your `kv` file being included in the `exe`?

Comment: I just realized with your comment that I forgot to add the kv file and now it’s starting well, thanks for your comment, it must have been tired.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.